# usage of sleep with multiple commands

Tags: unix

with what command we can start five commands in background each one sleeping for 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

In a shell, you could just do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10 && command1 &
sleep 10 && command2 &
sleep 10 && command3 &
sleep 10 && command4 &
sleep 10 && command5 &
```

The `&` at the end tells the command to be backgrounded.

To turn this into a general-purpose script, you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10 && $1 &
sleep 10 && $2 &
sleep 10 && $3 &
sleep 10 && $4 &
sleep 10 && $5 &
```

Usage:

```
./script 'echo 1' 'echo 2' 'echo 3' 'echo 4' 'echo 5'
```

Note: you usually want to quote parameters passed to shell scripts (i.e. `"$1"`) so spaces aren't split into words.  Because I didn't do that, the arguments are split into words, so it becomes `&& echo 1` instead of `&& "echo 1"`.  This works great for our trivial example, but not when you want to run `'/usr/bin/command with spaces'`

Comment: Oh maybe that's what he meant :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this? Sounds weird to me

```
sleep 10 &
sleep 10 &
sleep 10 &
sleep 10 &
sleep 10 &
```

Comment: Oh maybe that's what he meant :)